# What are some good explanations of the epsilon-delta definition of limits?

Tags: calculus, limits

I am reading Stewart Calculus 7e and have encountered the epsilon-delta definition of a limit again. There was a time when I understood it, but it required a great amount of thought. Does anyone know of any exceptionally clear explanations of the definition that include media such as pictures, videos, etc.? I have seen some really artistic answers on this site and was hoping somebody could post one about the epsilon-delta definition of the limit.

Comment: http://webspace.ship.edu/msrenault/GeoGebraCalculus/continuity_at_a_point.html

Answer (score 1):

$$
\lim_{x\to a} f(x) = L
$$
means $f(x)$ can be made as close to $L$ as desired by making $x$ close enough, but not equal, to $0$.

$\varepsilon$ is how close we want to make $f(x)$ to $L$, i.e. we want to make the distance between $f(x)$ and $L$ less than $\varepsilon$.

$\delta$ is how close we will make $x$ to $a$, i.e. we will make the distance between $x$ and $a$ less than $\delta$, but not $0$.

So $\lim\limits_{x\to a}f(x)=L$ means no matter how tiny $\varepsilon$ is made there is some value of $\delta$ small enough to guarantee that if the distance from $x$ to $a$ is less than $\delta$, but not $0$, then the distance from $f(x)$ to $L$ is less than $\varepsilon$.

I've done some graphics related to this in the past, and I'll have to look for that stuff.